# Debugger creation tutorial

Tags: debugging

Where can I find good tutorial for design and developing of a debugger? I searched trough, but I found only a few general articles about this topic. I need to know more in details: how its attached to an application, how and where in memory it sets a breakpoint, how it reads a stack trace? Also, I'm interested in general design of a debugger.

Comment: This is a very ambitious project. You will need an intimate knowledge of the language of the programs you want to debug and their execution environment (e.g. to write a C debugger, you need to be well-versed in C and the machine it runs on; to write a Java debugger, you will need to understand Java and the JVM).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing a debugger is no trivial task and it requires intimate knowledge both in the underlying platform you're working with and the language you're writing a debugger for.

Some articles I've came across in the past I found particular helpful on the subject:

- Eli Bendersky's "[**How debuggers work**](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/23/how-debuggers-work-part-1)". I found this to be pretty helpful thanks to its thoroughness. He covers all the important parts of what a debugger does, how it works and how it accomplishes this under the hood. He even covers quite a bit on using dwarf debug format to help annotate a debug session, a subject matter that's hard to come by given its lack of *accessible* documentation. Even though he covers this in a *nix-like platform, many of the concepts he describes are still just as applicable under Windows.
- DebugInfo.com [**DEBUGGING API EXAMPLES**](http://www.debuginfo.com/examples/dbgexamples.html). If you're intending to work on win32 platform then you'll find the examples here useful. This one shows actual examples of how you can use the win32 debugging api to create a process that can "act" like a debugger. It contains examples on how to launch the debuggee or attach to a running process and handling debug events generated from the debug api.
- [**MobDebug**](https://github.com/pkulchenko/MobDebug). This is a remote lua debugger implemented in pure lua in ~1.4kloc. This complement's deivid's answer on the ruby debugger. Many times it's helpful to see an actual implementation of a debugger even if it isn't for a low level language. This may be an easier place to start to get an overall view of what the debugger has to do without getting bogged down with all the lower level details you'll have to deal with in a "bare-metal" language.
- **[pydbg](https://github.com/OpenRCE/pydbg)**. A windows debugger written in python using the debugging API below.
- **[jewdbg](https://github.com/isislab/jewdbg)**. Another windows debugger written in python. A bit smaller than pydbg and not as feature rounded but great if you're looking for an example implementation to learn from.
- **[MSDN Debugging API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679303(VS.85).aspx)**. Primary reference & documentation for the basic debugging primitives and building blocks provided by windows. If developing your own debugger for windows you'll need many of the things provided here.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. That's why I accepted your answer.

Comment: Nice answer, man! I'll check those links!

Comment: @Miller I've added 3 more resource links in case you're still interested in debugger implementation.

Comment: Yes, thank you @greatwolf. This jewdbg is great debugger implementation. Nice and simple, just for beginners, but I wouldn't understand anything without first link Eli Bendersky's "How debuggers work". That explains a lot. Thanks again. I wish I could give you another up point.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I don't know of any guide like that... My recommendation is to pick the opensource programming language of your choice and read the debugger's source code... That's what I did and it worked.

For a concrete example, I know the ruby debugger.

- It works by setting some tracepoints for specific events like 'instruction execution', 'method call' or 'method return' and defining callback functions for them which keep track of things. For example, when an instruction is going to be executed, the debugger takes control and checks whether there's a breakpoint in that line. Then it returns control to either the user or the program being debugged depending on the previous check.
- Breakpoints are kept in a global variable by the debugger.
- Stack trace is checked normally (ruby provides tools to do that).

Answer (score 2):

You are facing a long journey to acomplish this. It's on my TODO list too ;)
check out tuts4you, and codeproject, they have some good tutorials.